# Is there a way to make the dash-dot border with square cap has same drawing direction with the shape to which it attached in SVG?

Tags: svg

I want to draw a dash-dot border with **square** cap, where the dot likes a 'square'. But I found setting the stoke length of the dot segment to be 0, resulting in a horizontal drawing.

To align the dot with the shape curve, I tried assigning a very tiny value to the dot segment (like `stroke-dasharray: 30 40 0.1 40;` instead of `stroke-dasharray: 30 40 0 40;`).
But this approach will *accumulate the tiny values*, causing a noticeable difference, especially when the shape is large.

I want to know if there is a better way to achieve my goal. Thanks for any help!

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 20px;
}

.roundcap-circle {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 30 40 0 40;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.squarecap1-circle {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-dasharray: 30 40 0 40;
  stroke-linecap: square;
}
.squarecap2-circle {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 30 40 0.1 40;
  stroke-linecap: square;
}

.roundcap-large-ellipse {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 20 0 20;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.squarecap-large-ellipse {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.1 20 0.1 20;
  stroke-linecap: square;
}

.mark {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg style="height:300px; width: 800px;">
  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" class="roundcap-circle" />
  <circle cx="400" cy="150" r="100" class="squarecap1-circle" />
  <circle cx="650" cy="150" r="100" class="squarecap2-circle" />
</svg>

<svg style="height:500px; width: 800px;">
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="250" rx="150" ry="200" class="roundcap-large-ellipse" />
  <ellipse cx="550" cy="250" rx="150" ry="200" class="squarecap-large-ellipse" />
  <circle cx="350" cy="250" r="20" class="mark" />
  <circle cx="700" cy="250" r="20" class="mark" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can ``pathLength`` help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

Comment: If you set `stroke-dasharray: 30 40 0.1 39.9`, the overall length remains unchanged. You could even do `stroke-dasharray: 30 39.95 0.1 39.95` to achieve a perfectly even distribution of space

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks! This attribute has help!

Comment: @ccprog You are genius! I finally use `PathLength`, this method will be easier, because I have other line styles to handle.